# data formatting with lodash

Tags: javascript, json, lodash, postgresql-9.2

suppose i have the following json array:

```
const input = [
  { "tx_type": "215", "dos": "2019-05-02", "payer": "Cigna", "count": 23 },
  { "tx_type": "215", "dos": "2019-05-02", "payer": "SENIORCARE Plus", "count": 75 },
  { "tx_type": "217", "dos": "2019-05-02", "payer": "Aetna", "count": 2 },
  { "tx_type": "215", "dos": "2019-05-03", "payer": "Aetna", "count": 85 },
  { "tx_type": "215", "dos": "2019-05-03", "payer": "TRICARE", "count": 1 },
  { "tx_type": "215", "dos": "2019-05-03", "payer": "Aetna", "count": 5 },
  { "tx_type": "215", "dos": "2019-05-03", "payer": "Cigna", "count": 11 }
]
```

which comes out of a postgres 9.2 db, but I am trying to fit the data into a dataviz that expects the data to look like:

```
[
  {
    "tx_type": "x215",
    "dos": [
      { "date": "2019-05-02", "SENIORCARE Plus": 75, "Cigna": 23 },
      { "date": "2019-05-03", "Aetna": 96, "TRICARE": 1, "Cigna": 11 }
    ],
  },
  {
    "tx_type": "x215",
    "dos": [
      { "date": "2019-05-02", "Aetna": 2 }
    ]
  }
]
```

i have tried using lodash to group the objects by tx_type using `.groupBy("tx_type")`, as well as `_.chain(input).nest("tx_type").groupBy("dos").value()`, as well as filtering by tx_type and then trying to group/ nest...

really, all I am trying to do is filter by tx_type and group the payers and counts by date.

any input would be greatly appreciated. and as much as i want to upgrading to a newer version of postgres isn't really an option..

Comment: note: I think you wanted to say `x217` on the 2nd obj in the expected results.

Comment: Sure you want the `payer` values as keys in results? Seems less firendly than standardized property names

Comment: @charlietfl I am following a d3js tutorial and this is the format it uses... I would tend to agree with you otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `tx_type` and map the groups. To create the `dos` property, map the items in the group, group them by `dos`, map the results to convert each row to an object of `{ data,  [payer]:count }`, and merge the objects:

```js
const input = [{"tx_type":"215","dos":"2019-05-02","payer":"Cigna","count":23},{"tx_type":"215","dos":"2019-05-02","payer":"SENIORCARE Plus","count":75},{"tx_type":"217","dos":"2019-05-02","payer":"Aetna","count":2},{"tx_type":"215","dos":"2019-05-03","payer":"Aetna","count":85},{"tx_type":"215","dos":"2019-05-03","payer":"TRICARE","count":1},{"tx_type":"215","dos":"2019-05-03","payer":"Aetna","count":5},{"tx_type":"215","dos":"2019-05-03","payer":"Cigna","count":11}]

const result = _(input)
  .groupBy('tx_type')
  .map((dos, tx_type) => ({
    tx_type,
    dos: _(dos)
      .groupBy('dos')
      .map((g, date) => _.merge({}, 
        ..._.map(g, ({ payer, count }) => ({ date,  [payer]: count }))
      ))
      .value()
  }))
  .value()
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-compat/3.10.2/lodash.js"></script>
```